# How to load the contents of a URL in a div tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to open a another page in `<div></div>` but when I do that it opens a new page.

I used `iframe` but that is discouraged, and it has scroll bars.

```
<div id="iframeLogin"><a href="first.php" target="_self">Link</a></div>
```

Is there anyway to open a page to this div?

I want it to autoload the page on to the `DIV` when I access the site.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid AJAX?

Comment: You can't 'open a page' inside of a div. Please give us more details as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm wondering if CURL would help you out, but need more details.

Comment: Having one page load "another page" within it is what iframes are for, especially if the other page is self-contained in the sense of having `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags. You can remove the scrollbars from an iframe.

Comment: @Eli Nevermind. if it can solve my problem i'll use it.

Comment: @DA like an iframe, Iframe opens page in a page, right? i have a main page that consist of 2 Frames, 1 frame have a HTML content, and the 2nd have another HTML content.

Comment: I frames create a 'hole' in your current page's DOM to load an external page. That's what they were designed for. A DIV can't do that. Really, the only reason to use an iFrame, though, is if you are loading pages that aren't on your own server. If it's your own server, there are likely much better ways to accomplish what you want to accomplish, but it's hard for us to know exactly what you are aiming for.

Comment: Avoid an iframe at all costs, the performance woes, maintenance, and cross-frame access headaches are not worth it. AJAX would be much easier.

Comment: @Eli but if i use AJAX to put a page in the `div`. I cant interact with it Ex: `<input type="text" id="ex1"/><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('ex1').value='example1'"/>`, unless the page that i put in the div will change the page. thats what i experienced using AJAX.

Comment: That is the correct way to do it, it is how single-page applications operate.

Comment: @Eli what if the page that i load using AJAX is using an AJAX too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method.

```
$(function() {
    $("#iframeLogin").load("first.php");
});
```

Note that if `first.php` is a complete HTML page, you'll want to only load a portion of the page.

`$("#iframeLogin").load("first.php #content");`

Comment: what if i use `$(document).ready(function(){$("#iframeLogin").load("first.php #content");});`?

Comment: That would be the same result. The syntax I used is just a shortcut for the DOM's ready handler. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more info.